# Move a files only in the git index without a working directory

Tags: git, internals

In preparation for rolling multiple repos into a single monorepo, I want to go through my entire repo history and move everything into a subdirectory `foo/` in every commit.

The fast (faster than `--tree-filter` at least) way of doing this seems to be with `filter-branch` and the `--index-filter` filter. However, with this approach you only have the index to work against, not a working tree. So how would I add a new directory and move all files into it for each commit's subtree?

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of `git rm --cached`, but `git mv` doesn't seem to provide this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `git mv --cached` or `git mv --after` (see `hg mv --after` for comparison).  There *should* be, in my opinion, but there isn't.

So [I wrote one](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-mv-after).  It's a little cheesey but it should work for your case, provided you have no files with control-A characters in their names.  If you want to move entire sub-trees of files, you'll probably want to fancy it up, and maybe write it in something other than shell script.